# Polymer installation too granular

Tags: polymer

I think the writers of Polymer have gone too far when it comes to installing dependencies.

I mean - who would do this?

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/gold-cc-cvc-input
```

You want to install the cvc-input and not the rest of the gold elements? I would like to install ALL Polymer elements for proof-of-concepts.

Q: Is there a way to install all Polymer elements so that I can write some proof-of-concepts based on their demos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each group of components there is aggregate bower package with all elements.

**Iron elements** - https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-elements

**Paper elements** - https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-elements

**Neon elements** - https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-elements

**Gold elements** - https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-elements

**Platinium elements** - https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-elements

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you'd want to use this method to install all elements.....but....

You can create a collection of elements via [open-elements.org](http://open-elements.org/), which produces a group of bower commands that can be used to install multiple elements in one go.

For example creating a collection of the gold elements would give the following command:

`bower install --save PolymerElements/gold-cc-cvc-input#^1.0.0 PolymerElements/gold-cc-expiration-input#^1.0.0 PolymerElements/gold-cc-input#^1.0.0 PolymerElements/gold-email-input#^1.0.0 PolymerElements/gold-phone-input#^1.0.0 PolymerElements/gold-zip-input#^1.0.0 PolymerElements/iron-collapse#^1.0.0 PolymerElements/paper-badge#^1.0.0 PolymerElements/paper-styles#^1.0.0`

This would also save them to the project dependencies.